# Cannot convert type `Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection' to `System.Data.IDbConnection'?

Tags: c#, npgsql

Why does the following give an error: "Cannot convert type Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection to System.Data.IDbConnection" ?

```
  IDbConnection c = (IDbConnection) new NpgsqlConnection("..snip..");
```

NpgsqlConnection inherits from DbConnection which implements IDbConnection.

Comment: @GrantWinney It seems to be like this: http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.html

Comment: @Icepickle yes, that's the API, thanks

Comment: I downloaded the library, with the matching .net framework version, and i could execute the same statement without problems... As the library is available for several .net assemblies, could you specify any better what target versions you are using (.net, npgsql). Check your references as well...

Comment: That cast is not really needed.

Comment: Npgsql-2.2.3-net35, Mono 2.10.11 (Unity3D version). There is other weirdness I get with this lib like:

"Argument '#1' cannot convert 'Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection' expression to type 'Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection'".

I can get it to compile and run, but then I refactor the code and it breaks the compile in these weird ways.